# How to solve $x^{x^{x^{x^{2010}}}} = 2010$

Tags: exponentiation, power-towers

So I know that there is a difference between $(x^2)^3$ and $x^{2^3}$.

But how do I use this knowledge to solve $$x^{x^{x^{x^{2010}}}} = 2010?$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Why stop at four of them, why not 2010?

Comment: @RossMillikan No, this is a riddle that has a nice analytical solution. I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint: if $x = a^{1/a}$, then $x^a = a$, $x^{x^a} = x^a = a$, and so on.

Comment: I mean yeah, this works perfectly. But how did you come up with such an approach ?

Comment: @Caito one way to approach problems of this nature is to solve similar yet easier problems and look for patterns. First of all there is nothing special about $2010$ so you can consider $x^{x^{x^{x^a}}} = a$. Second, you can consider the easier problems $x^{x^{x^a}} = a$, $x^{x^a} = a$, and $x^a = a$. The last one is trivial, and once you realize the last two problems have the same solution the general solution is apparent.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $x>0$ since the expression on the LHS is not generally defined for $x\leq 0$. Suppose $x\in(0,1]$. Then $x^{x^{x^{2010}}}$ is a positive number, so $f(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^{2010}}}}\in(0,1]$, and there are no solutions in this interval. Now suppose $x>1$. $f$ is strictly increasing. Let $x>y>1$. Then $x^{2010}>y^{2010}$ which implies $x^{x^{2010}}>y^{y^{2010}}$, and continuing this, we get $f(x)>f(y)$. This means it has no more than $1$ positive solution. Let $a=\sqrt[2010]{2010}$. Notice that $a^{2010}=2010$. So
$$a^{a^{a^{a^{2010}}}}=a^{a^{a^{2010}}}=a^{a^{2010}}=a^{2010}=2010 $$
Hence, $x=a$ is the only (positive) solution. $b=-\sqrt[2010]{2010}$ also satisfies $b^{2010}=2010$ so that would be a negative solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this equation is $$x=\sqrt[2010]{2010}.$$ The proof is quite easy. Maybe now you can complete it yourself :)